# Recurrence with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to make recurrence without using for's in numpy?

Using `np.add` with `out` keyword do the trick with `dtype="int"`

```
import numpy as np
N = 100

fib = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int)
fib[:2] = 1.
np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])

print(fib[:10])
```

output: `[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55]`

However, if `dtype` is changed to np.float

```
import numpy as np
N = 100

fib = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float)
fib[:2] = 1.
np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])

print(fib[:10])
```

output: `[ 1.  1.  2.  1.  3.  1.  4.  1.  5.  1.]`

Could someone tell me why? or any other way to make recursion?

Comment: The behavior you're relying on was never actually defined, and [they changed it in NumPy 1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs). Neither of your snippets will work in 1.13.

Comment: note that your code doesn't use recursion anyway...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at english. I guess I mean recurrence. when an array is defined as a function of the preceding terms

Comment: @user2357112 you are right. Neither of my snippets will work. Do you know  how to get fibonacci efficiently with numpy?

Comment: @pablo2303 It sounds like you're looking for guaranteed sequential evaluation, in a guaranteed order.  The best way to achieve that is with an explicit loop that evaluates one result value at a time, in an order that you control.

Comment: fibonacci is inherently an iterative calculation.  The `ith` value is the sum of the previous two.  `numpy` is best for calculations that work with the whole array (list) in parallel (it doesn't matter whether the i'th element is calculated before or after the j'th one, or at the same time).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890448/numpys-matrix-power-function-giving-wrong-results-for-large-exponents is an example of Fibonacci Q-Matrix.  But under the covers `matrix_power` is iterative and thus not particularly efficient.

Comment: @hpaulj , thanks for the example. But I used fibonacci as an example. What I try to do is to solve an ODE with central difference method. Also, the approach using `np.add` (which was never defined) is 15 times faster than using for. That's why I would like to get a numpy approach.

Comment: @pablo2303 have you considered using an [ODE solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/integrate.html)?

Comment: `np.add` even with the `out` parameter is buffered.  There is a `add.at` to get around that.  It still runs at compiled speed, but is somewhat slower than the buffered add.  `add` gets its speed because its speed because it is compiled; it still iterates.

Comment: It looks like version `1.13` is using a larger buffer (docs talk about changes in the in-place buffering).  My `np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])` does not give any recursion, where as your's has full or partial recursion depending on dtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reasonably efficient method using a scipy filter:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def scipy_fib(n):
    x = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.uint8)
    x[0] = 1

    sos = signal.tf2sos([1], [1, -1, -1])
    return signal.sosfilt(sos, x)
```

(Note that we can't use `lfilter` because in terms of signal processing this is an unstable filter which makes the Python interpreter crash, so we have to convert to second-order sections form.)

The problem with the filtering approach is that I'm not sure if it can be generalized to the actual problem of solving an ODE.

Another solution is to simply write the loop in Python and accelerate it with a [JIT compiler](https://numba.pydata.org/):

```
import numba as nb    

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_fib(n):
    y = np.empty(n)
    y[:2] = 1

    for i in range(2, n):
        y[i] = y[i-1] + y[i-2]

    return y
```

The advantage of the JIT approach is that you can implement all kinds of fancy stuff, but it works best if you stick to simple loops and branches without calling any (non-JITted) Python functions.

Timing results:

```
# Baseline without JIT:
%timeit numba_fib(10000)  # 100 loops, best of 3: 5.47 ms per loop

%timeit scipy_fib(10000)  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 719 µs per loop
%timeit numba_fib(10000)  # 10000 loops, best of 3: 33.8 µs per loop

# For fun, this is how Paul Panzer's solve_banded approach compares:
%timeit banded_fib(10000)  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
```

The scipy filter approach is faster than the pure Python loop but slower than the JITted loop. I guess the filter function is relatively generic and does stuff we don't need here, while the JITted loop compiles down to a very small loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` works for this calculation, but has to be applied repeatedly, so that the nonzero values propagate.  I don't see how your calculation generated `[ 1.  1.  2.  1.  3.  1.  4.  1.  5.  1.]`.

```
In [619]: fib=np.zeros(10,int);fib[:2]=1
In [620]: for _ in range(10):
     ...:     np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])
     ...:     print(fib)
     ...: 
[1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]   # **
[1 1 2 3 3 1 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 2 3 5 6 4 1 0 0]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 11 10  5  1]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 19 21 15]
 ...
```

(edit - 
Note that the first `np.add` acts as though it is fully buffered.  Compare the result at ** with both of your object and float arrays.  I'm using version 1.13.1 on Py3.)

Or to highlight the good values at each stage

```
In [623]: fib=np.zeros(20,int);fib[:2]=1
In [624]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])
     ...:     print(fib[:(i+2)])
     ...: 
[1 1]
[1 1 2]
[1 1 2 3]
[1 1 2 3 5]
[1 1 2 3 5 8]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55]
[ 1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55 89]
```

`fib[2:] = fib[:-2]+fib[1:-1]` does the same thing.

As discussed in the documentation for `ufunc.at`, operations like `np.add` use buffering, even with the `out` parameter.  So while they do interate in `C` level code, they don't accumulate; that is, results from the `ith` step aren't used at the `i+1` step.

`add.at` can be used to perform unbuffered `a[i] += b`.  That's handy when the indexes contain dupicates. but it doesn't allow for feedback from the changed `a` values to `b`.  So it isn't useful here.

The is also a `add.accumulate` (aka `np.cumsum`) which can be handy for certain iterative definitions.  But it's hard to apply in general cases.

`cumprod` (multiply accumulate) can work with the `qmatrix` approach

[Numpy's matrix_power function giving wrong results for large exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890448/numpys-matrix-power-function-giving-wrong-results-for-large-exponents)

Use `np.matrix` to define the `qmatrix`, so that `*` multiply means matrix product (as opposed to elementwise):

```
In [647]: qmatrix = numpy.matrix([[1, 1], [1, 0]])
```

Populate an object matrix with copies (pointers actually) to this matrix.

```
In [648]: M = np.empty(10, object)
In [649]: M[:] = [qmatrix for _ in range(10)]
```

Apply `cumprod`, and extract one element from each matrix.

```
In [650]: m1=np.cumprod(M)
In [651]: m1
Out[651]: 
array([matrix([[1, 1],
        [1, 0]]), matrix([[2, 1],
        [1, 1]]),
       matrix([[3, 2],
        [2, 1]]), matrix([[5, 3],
        [3, 2]]),
       matrix([[8, 5],
        [5, 3]]),
       matrix([[13,  8],
        [ 8,  5]]),
       matrix([[21, 13],
        [13,  8]]),
       matrix([[34, 21],
        [21, 13]]),
       matrix([[55, 34],
        [34, 21]]),
       matrix([[89, 55],
        [55, 34]])], dtype=object)
In [652]: [x[0,1] for x in m1]
Out[652]: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

The linked answer uses `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` which also does repeated matrix products.  For a single power, `matrix_power` is faster, but for a whole range of powers, the `cumprod` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

One maybe not super-efficent but fun solution would be to abuse `scipy.linalg.solve_banded` like so

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

N = 50
a = np.zeros((N,)) + np.array([[1, -1, -1]]).T
b = np.zeros((N,))
b[0] = 1
linalg.solve_banded((2, 0), a, b)
# array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,
#          3.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,
#          1.30000000e+01,   2.10000000e+01,   3.40000000e+01,
#          5.50000000e+01,   8.90000000e+01,   1.44000000e+02,
#          2.33000000e+02,   3.77000000e+02,   6.10000000e+02,
#          9.87000000e+02,   1.59700000e+03,   2.58400000e+03,
#          4.18100000e+03,   6.76500000e+03,   1.09460000e+04,
#          1.77110000e+04,   2.86570000e+04,   4.63680000e+04,
#          7.50250000e+04,   1.21393000e+05,   1.96418000e+05,
#          3.17811000e+05,   5.14229000e+05,   8.32040000e+05,
#          1.34626900e+06,   2.17830900e+06,   3.52457800e+06,
#          5.70288700e+06,   9.22746500e+06,   1.49303520e+07,
#          2.41578170e+07,   3.90881690e+07,   6.32459860e+07,
#          1.02334155e+08,   1.65580141e+08,   2.67914296e+08,
#          4.33494437e+08,   7.01408733e+08,   1.13490317e+09,
#          1.83631190e+09,   2.97121507e+09,   4.80752698e+09,
#          7.77874205e+09,   1.25862690e+10])
```

How this works is that we write F_0, F_1, F_2... as one vector F and the identities -F_{i-1} -F_i + F{i+1} = 0 as a matrix which is nicely banded and then solve for F. Note that this can adapted to other similar recurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Since linear recurrences have analytic solutions  ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for Fibonacci), another rapid scipy method is :

```
import math

import numpy as np

def fib_scipy2(N):
    r5=math.sqrt(5)
    phi=(1+r5)/2
    a= (-phi*np.ones(N)).cumprod()
    return (np.abs(a)-1/a)/r5
```

Runs:

```
In [413]: fib_scipy2(8)
Out[413]: array([  1.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   5.,   8.,  13.,  21.])
In [414]: %timeit fib_scipy2(10**4)
103 µs ± 888 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

You can tune it to any linear equation.