# The `out` arguments in `numpy.einsum` can not work as expected

Tags: numpy, python-3.5

I have two piece codes. The first one is:

```
A = np.arange(3*4*3).reshape(3, 4, 3)
P = np.arange(1, 4)
A[:, 1:, :] = np.einsum('j, ijk->ijk', P, A[:, 1:, :])
```

and the result `A` is :

```
array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [  6,   8,  10],
        [ 18,  21,  24],
        [ 36,  40,  44]],

       [[ 12,  13,  14],
        [ 30,  32,  34],
        [ 54,  57,  60],
        [ 84,  88,  92]],

       [[ 24,  25,  26],
        [ 54,  56,  58],
        [ 90,  93,  96],
        [132, 136, 140]]])
```

The second one is:

```
A = np.arange(3*4*3).reshape(3, 4, 3)
P = np.arange(1, 4)
np.einsum('j, ijk->ijk', P, A[:, 1:, :], out=A[:,1:,:])
```

and the result `A` is :

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

So the result is different. Here I want to use `out` to save memory. Is it a bug in `numpy.einsum`? Or I missed something?

By the way, my `numpy` version is 1.13.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used this new `out` parameter before, but have worked with `einsum` in the past, and have a general idea of how it works (or at least used to).

It looks to me like it initializes the `out` array to zero before the start of iteration.  That would account for all the 0s in the `A[:,1:,:]` block.  If instead I initial separate `out` array, the desired values are inserted

```
In [471]: B = np.ones((3,4,3),int)
In [472]: np.einsum('j, ijk->ijk', P, A[:, 1:, :], out=B[:,1:,:])
Out[472]: 
array([[[  3,   4,   5],
        [ 12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33]],

       [[ 15,  16,  17],
        [ 36,  38,  40],
        [ 63,  66,  69]],

       [[ 27,  28,  29],
        [ 60,  62,  64],
        [ 99, 102, 105]]])
In [473]: B
Out[473]: 
array([[[  1,   1,   1],
        [  3,   4,   5],
        [ 12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33]],

       [[  1,   1,   1],
        [ 15,  16,  17],
        [ 36,  38,  40],
        [ 63,  66,  69]],

       [[  1,   1,   1],
        [ 27,  28,  29],
        [ 60,  62,  64],
        [ 99, 102, 105]]])
```

The Python portion of `einsum` doesn't tell me much, except how it decides to pass the `out` array to the `c` portion, (as one of the list of `tmp_operands`):

c_einsum(einsum_str, *tmp_operands, **einsum_kwargs)

I know that it sets up a `c-api` equivalent of `np.nditer`, using the `str` to define the axes and iterations.

It iterates something like this section in the iteration tutorial:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#reduction-iteration

Notice in particular the `it.reset()` step.  That sets the `out` buffer to  0 prior to iterating.  It then iterates over the elements of input arrays and the output array, writing the calculation values to the output element.  Since it is doing a sum of products (e.g. `out[:] += ...`), it has to start with a clean slate.

I'm guessing a bit as to what is actually going on, but it seems logical to me that it should zero out the output buffer to start with.  If that array is the same as one of the inputs, that will end up messing with the calculation.

So I don't think this approach will work and save you memory.  It needs a clean buffer to accumulate the results in.  Once that's done it, or you, can write the values back into `A`.  But given the nature of a `dot` like product, you can't use the same array for input and for output.

```
In [476]: A[:,1:,:] = np.einsum('j, ijk->ijk', P, A[:, 1:, :])
In [477]: A
Out[477]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [  3,   4,   5],
        [ 12,  14,  16],
        [ 27,  30,  33]],
        ....)
```

Comment: hpaulj, @ely does either of you know whether this is (or should be) in any way related to this new _"Inplace operations check if inputs overlap outputs and create temporaries to avoid problems."_ feature in [numpy1.13](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html)?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I suspect from the release notes that there's a change in handling of `+=` like operations, and related `ufunc`.  `np.add(fib[:-2], fib[1:-1], out=fib[2:])`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427603/recurrence-with-numpy, gives different results dtype and version (12 v 13).  In `13` it looks like the whole array is buffered and  there's no recursion.  But even with an `out` parameter, `einsum` is not a `ufunc`.

Answer (score 3):

In the C source code for `einsum`, [there is a section](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/088c565bd959e90b2cf3a0d0c5450d41b7830ca6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src#L2892) that will take the array specified by `out` and do some zero-setting.

But in the [Python source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/088c565bd959e90b2cf3a0d0c5450d41b7830ca6/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py#L1120) for example, there are execution paths that call the `tensordot` function before ever descending the arguments to call `c_einsum`.

This means that some operations might be pre-computed (thus modifying your array `A` on some contraction passes) with `tensordot`, *before* any sub-array is ever set to zero by the zero-setter inside the C code for einsum.

Another way to put it is: on each pass at doing the next contraction operations, NumPy has many choices available to it. To use `tensordot` directly without getting into the C-level einsum code just yet? Or to prepare the arguments and pass to the C level (which will involve over-writing some sub-view of the output array with all zeros)? Or to re-order the operations and repeat the check?

Depending on the order it chooses for these optimizations, you can end up with unexpected all-zeros sub-arrays.

Best bet is to not try to be this clever and use the same array for the output. You say it is because you want to save memory. Yes, in some special cases an einsum operation might be do-able in-place. But it does not currently detect if this is the case and attempt to avoid the zero-setting.

And in a huge number of cases, over-writing into one of the input arrays during the middle of the overall operation would cause many problems, much like trying to append to a list you are directly looping over, etc.