# How to improve the efficiency of array operation on the index view of a `numpy` array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following is an example code which compute array `B` from `A`:

```
import numpy as np
idx1 = np.array([
 [3, 0, 0],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 3]])
idx2 = np.arange(3)
A = np.arange(10*4*3).reshape(10, 4, 3)
B = np.prod(A[:, idx1, idx2], axis=2)
```

Notice the line

```
B = np.prod(A[:, idx1, idx2], axis=2)
```

Is this line memory efficent? Or does `numpy` will generate some internal array for `A[:, idx1, idx2]`?

One can image that if `len(A)` is very large, and `numpy` generate some internal array for `A[:, idx1, idx2]`, it is not memory efficient. Does there exist any better way to do such thing?

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory?  If so, how much memory do you have, and what shapes are your actual data?

Comment: @JohnZwinck In fact, I am not running out of memory.  I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is parsed and evaluated by the Python interpreter:

```
B = np.prod(A[:, idx1, idx2], axis=2)
```

first it does

```
temp = A[:, idx1, idx2]   # expands to:
temp = A.__getitem__(slice(None), idx1, idx2)
```

Since `idx1`, `idx2` are arrays, this is `advanced indexing`, and `temp` is a copy, not a view.

Next the interpret executes:

```
np.prod(temp, axis=2)
```

that is, it passes temporary array to the `prod` function, which then returns an array, which is assigned to the `B` variable.

I don't know how much buffering `prod` does.  I can imagine it setting up a `nditer` (c-api version) that takes two operand arrays, the `temp` and an output of the right shape (`temp.shape(:-1)` assuming the sum is on the last dimension of `temp`).  See the `reduction` section of the docs that I cited in [The `out` arguments in `numpy.einsum` can not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492316/the-out-arguments-in-numpy-einsum-can-not-work-as-expected).

In sum, Python, when evaluating a function, first evaluates all the arguments, and then passes them to the function.  Evaluation of lists can be delayed by using generators, but there isn't an equivalent for numpy arrays.