# How to create array with initial value and 'decay function'?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a more efficient way to compute this (searched for something similar to numpy's arange):

```
R = 0
l1 = []
gamma = 0.99
x = 12
for i in range(0, 1000):       
    R = x - (1-gamma) * R
    l1.append(R)
```

the iteration and appending are too slow

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47429565/3005167) gives you a few ideas.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. Creating a list of 1000 values using the loop in your code completes very quickly. All but the first few values are the same (due to floating point precision, I suspect, otherwise they'd continue to converge on some real number). If you're using a different calculation in your real code, please show it. There might be a way to compute the same results using a closed-form formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an easy factor of 3 if you JIT the function using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org):

[image: Numba JIT]

You should also explore Numpy and play around in a notebook or IPython to do some performance tests depending on your typical input and come back if you have more specific questions.

**Just a small update:**
With Julia (https://julialang.org) I get something around 2.5us, so there is still room for improvement ;)

[image: Using Julia]